# Adding values to matrix from a single variable in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, matrix, plot

I have a problem where i can't add values to my 1 x 250 matrix directly from a variable. This is the code.

```
COMPORT = 'COM4';
BAUDRATE = 115200;
s1 = serial(COMPORT, 'baudrate', BAUDRATE);
set(s1, 'Terminator', 10);
fopen(s1);
adc = 0;
N = 250;
values = zeros(1, N);
for n = 1:N
   adc = fscanf(s1);
   values(n) = adc;
   flushinput(s1);
   flushoutput(s1);
end
x = linspace(0, 250);
plot(x, n);
```

The values(n) = adc does not seem to work and i don't know how to work my way around it.

Comment: which error do you get? and which value does the variable adc holds?

Comment: Attempted to access adc(5); index out of bounds because numel(adc)=4.

Error in sensorTest (line 11)
   values(n) = adc(n);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because `values(n)` is a single element and the output from `fscanf(s1)` consist of several elements.

Maybe you want to use cells?

```
values{n} = adc;
```

Substitute the pre-allocation: `n = zeros(1, N)` with `n = cell(1,N);`.

Notice that you need to do some changes later in your code. I'll leave that uo to you.